# How can I get logged in user's session data from admin-ajax?

Tags: ajax, admin, session

I have hooked an ajax call for a logged-in user, and now I need to catch his data inside the receiving call (the code that receives the action call). How can I get the user's ID reliably? This code is inside my plugin definition file and the code inside the function (error_log("we're in....kind of");) is being called:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_team', 'create_team' );
 function create_team() {

    error_log("we're in....kind of");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`wp_get_current_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) will get you the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object for the currently logged-in user:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_team', 'create_team' );
function create_team() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $current_user->ID;
    die;
}
```

Comment: This is actually working fine, I didn't think it would work easily like that, but that more check had to be done. Looks like the session data is actually sent through Ajax. Am I correct? :) Anyway, this answer is just what I need.

Comment: WordPress doesn't use sessions, logged-in state is stored in cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific data for your ajax hook, you need to send it with your request.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'user_id': 1234
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

often times `wp_localize_script` is used as a handy way to output php data as javascript objects that you can then read from the `window` object.

Comment: it looks like I don't have to send it as a payload. It is already available on the server PHP side (see Milo's answer).

Comment: omg are you dumb or what ? Anyone can modify the user_id value on front end, it is not good practice and very insecure.

Comment: @AumkarThakur I am sure this user has learned more about coding since 2017. I hope you have learned more about communicating since 2019. ;)
I'm currently sending along the user_id as honeypot as I'm needing to get and send GPS coordinates. Not much we can trust.

Comment: Wow @AumkarThakur you must be a really hard person to work/live near. What an obnoxious and ignorant comment.